# Display a person from contacts - iPhone Programming

Tags: iphone, ios, uiviewcontroller

How do I display a person (AdressBookUI framework) in my iPhone app. I already have an ABRecordRef for the person, but I just need to display them.

Also, I'd like to only display their name, their picture, and their phone numbers. How do I do that?

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used the tutorial here to help me figure out the basics

http://blog.slaunchaman.com/2009/01/21/cocoa-touch-tutorial-extract-address-book-address-values-on-iphone-os/